# NumPy C-API: Undefined reference error trying to support numpy.float16

Tags: python, c, numpy, linker-errors, meson-build

I am trying to build one of the `ufunc` examples from NumPy's documentation (see [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html#example-numpy-ufunc-with-multiple-dtypes)), but I am unable to get the support for half-precision floating point numbers to work.

This is my minimal example:

`pyproject.toml`

```ini
[build-system]
build-backend = "mesonpy"
requires = ["meson-python==0.15", "numpy==1.26.3"]

[project]
name = "mypackage"
version = "0.1.0"
dependencies = ["numpy==1.26.3"]
```

`meson.build` - There's an [open issue](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/9598) on GitHub regarding adding NumPy as a build dependency in Meson - the custom lookup in the code below follows what seems to be the [current recommendation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/730010e77319606718b3d50a8fc402ba9cc629bc/scipy/meson.build#L30-L77) from the SciPy project on how to add the NumPy headers.

```
project(
    'mypackage',
    'c',
    version: '0.1.0'
)

py = import('python').find_installation(pure: false)

incdir_numpy = meson.get_external_property('numpy-include-dir', 'not-given')
if incdir_numpy == 'not-given'
  incdir_numpy = run_command(
    py,
    ['-c', '''
import os
import numpy
try:
    incdir = os.path.relpath(numpy.get_include())
except Exception:
    incdir = numpy.get_include()
print(incdir)
'''
    ],
    check: true
  ).stdout().strip()
  _incdir_numpy_abs = run_command(
    py,
    ['-c', '''
import os
import numpy
print(numpy.get_include())
'''
    ],
    check: true
  ).stdout().strip()
else
  _incdir_numpy_abs = incdir_numpy
endif
inc_np = include_directories(incdir_numpy)
numpy_nodepr_api = ['-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_26_API_VERSION']
np_dep = declare_dependency(include_directories: inc_np, compile_args: numpy_nodepr_api)

py.extension_module(
    'npufunc',
    'npufunc.c',
    dependencies: np_dep,
    install: true
)
```

`npufunc.c` - This is just straightforward copy & paste from the [example](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html#example-numpy-ufunc-with-multiple-dtypes). I removed the methods for other data types (single, double, etc.), since they don't cause trouble.

```c
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include "numpy/ndarraytypes.h"
#include "numpy/ufuncobject.h"
#include "numpy/halffloat.h"
#include <math.h>

static PyMethodDef LogitMethods[] = {
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static void half_float_logit(char **args, const npy_intp *dimensions,
                            const npy_intp *steps, void *data)
{
    npy_intp i;
    npy_intp n = dimensions[0];
    char *in = args[0], *out = args[1];
    npy_intp in_step = steps[0], out_step = steps[1];

    float tmp;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tmp = npy_half_to_float(*(npy_half *)in);
        tmp /= 1 - tmp;
        tmp = logf(tmp);
        *((npy_half *)out) = npy_float_to_half(tmp);

        in += in_step;
        out += out_step;
    }
}

PyUFuncGenericFunction funcs[1] = {&half_float_logit};

static char types[2] = {NPY_HALF, NPY_HALF};

static struct PyModuleDef moduledef = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "npufunc",
    NULL,
    -1,
    LogitMethods,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_npufunc(void)
{
    PyObject *m, *logit, *d;

    import_array();
    import_umath();

    m = PyModule_Create(&moduledef);
    if (!m) {
        return NULL;
    }

    logit = PyUFunc_FromFuncAndData(funcs, NULL, types, 1, 1, 1,
                                    PyUFunc_None, "logit",
                                    "logit_docstring", 0);

    d = PyModule_GetDict(m);

    PyDict_SetItemString(d, "logit", logit);
    Py_DECREF(logit);

    return m;
}
```

But I am getting an error from the linker when using GCC 13.2 (via [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) - I'm working on Windows 10):

```
[2/2] Linking target npufunc.cp312-win_amd64.pyd
FAILED: npufunc.cp312-win_amd64.pyd
"cc"  -o npufunc.cp312-win_amd64.pyd npufunc.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/npufunc.c.obj "-Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined" "-Wl,-O1" "-shared" "-Wl,--start-group" "-Wl,--out-implib=npufunc.cp312-win_amd64.dll.a" "C:\Program Files\Python312\python312.dll" "l" "-lkernel32" "-luser32" "-lgdi32" "-lwinspool" "-lshell32" "-lole32" "-loleaut32" "-luuid" "-lcomdlg32" "-ladvapi32"-,-" "-Wl,--end-group"
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: npufunc.cp312-win_amd_amd64.pyd.p/npufunc.c.obj:npufunc.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `npy_half_to_float'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: npufunc.cp312-win_amd_amd64.pyd.p/npufunc.c.obj:npufunc.c:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `npy_float_to_half'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Switching to MSVC 19.38 doesn't help either:

```
[2/2] Linking target npufunc.cp312-win_amd64.pyd
FAILED: npufunc.cp312-win_amd64.pyd
"link"  /MACHINE:x64 /OUT:npufunc.cp312-win_amd64.pyd npufunc.cp312-win_amd64.pyd.p/npufunc.c.obj "/release" "/nologo" "/OPT:REF" "/DLL" "/IMPLIB:npufunc.cp312-win_amd64.lib" "C:\Program Files\Python312\libs\python312.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib"       
   Creating library npufunc.cp312-win_amd64.lib and object npufunc.cp312-win_amd64.exp
npufunc.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol npy_half_to_float referenced in function half_float_logit       
npufunc.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol npy_float_to_half referenced in function half_float_logit       
npufunc.cp312-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I understand that dealing with 16-bit floating point numbers can be somewhat  "iffy", due to a lack of hardware support on most CPUs. But I'm including the correct header `"numpy/halffloat.h"`, that defines the two conversion functions `npy_half_to_float` and `npy_float_to_half`.

Why am I seeing this error? Any pointers in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You're including the header, but that just says what the function names and signatures should be. You still need to link against the actual implementation of those functions. I don't know enough about Meson to be able to say how you would do that, though.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! The `declare_dependency(...)` and `py.extension_module(..., dependencies: np_dep)` parts in the `meson.build` should take care of that. For example, I can replace the half-precision method with the single or double precision method from the NumPy docs, and everything works just fine. The linker finds the other includes. For some reason, it's specifically the `"numpy/halffloat.h"` header that's causing issues. It's in the same location than the other headers, though. I did check that.

Comment: The linker doesn't have anything to do with header files. Those are handled by the preprocessor. Looking at the output you posted, it's linking against C:\Program Files\Python312\python312.dll, but it doesn't look like it's linking against any NumPy files.

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.12.0/scipy/meson.build#L79-L82) is where SciPy finds the NumPy libraries to link against, but I'm not sure where it actually tells the linker to link against those files.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link. Admittedly, I'm still confused as to why the linker appears to find some NumPy libraries (whichever ones contain the code that corresponds to those other two headers `"numpy/ndarraytypes.h"` and `"numpy/ufuncobject.h"`), but not the half-precision one. But from that code section you shared, it looks like NumPy's libs are split across several files, that I'll have to find and tell the linker about ...